# how to get to the target floor in minimum time if one can move to N + 1, N - 1 and 2 * N in one minute?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is a problem I was asked to solve during an interview, but the code I implemented during interview cannot pass all test cases, the problem is just as title said, given N and T (T >= N), which  are initial floor and target floor respectively, one can move to current floor + 1, current floor - 1 or 2 * current floor in one minute, what's the minimum time need to reach the target? I think it's a typical DP problem, this is how I did in interview

```
@lru_cache(None)
def solve(cur):
    if cur >= target: return cur - target
    if cur * 2 >= target:
        # if current floor * 2 < target, we can move to current floor + 1 each time or move backward to (target + 1) // 2 and move current floor * 2 next time, and if target is odd, we need extra 1 move
        return min(target - cur, cur - (target + 1) // 2 + 1 + (target % 2))
    return min(solve(cur + 1), solve(cur * 2)) + 1
```

I test it with some cases, it seems to work, I cannot figure out why it cannot pass all test cases during interview,

Update---------------------------------------------------------------

I tried using Dijkstra to solve this, but the code become a bit of mess, than I thought if the problem askes to find shortest distance, maybe we can use BFS, and I think it's the right solution, so below is the code

```
def solve():
    while(True):
        N, T = map(int, input().split())
        q = deque([N])
        vis = [False] * (T * 2)
        vis[N] = True
        steps = 0
        while q:
            for _ in range(len(q)):
                u = q.popleft()
                if u == T:
                    print(f'reach target in {steps} minutes')
                    break
                cand = [u - 1, u + 1, u * 2] if u < T else [u - 1]
                for v in cand:
                    if v > 0 and not vis[v]:
                        vis[v] = True
                        q.append(v)
            steps += 1
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of a test case that it fails on?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand `cur - (target + 1) // 2 + 1 + (target % 2)` part, shouldn't it be `1 + cur*2 - target`?

Comment: The `N-1` option complicates this and means that you can't just use straight-forward naïve DP.  You probably need some kind of Branch and Bound combined with DP, using `ABS(target - cur)` as the upper bound and `Log2(ABS(target - cur))` as the lower bound.

Comment: @Iłya Bursov if target is odd, say 17, and n = 5, than it would be 5 -> 10 -> 9 -> 18 -> 17, extra 1 is for 18 -> 17

Comment: @zenxy if target is 17 and n is 5 - you will not be in this branch

Comment: An instance where your algorithm gives the incorrect answer is `N=7`, `T=24`. The correct answer is 3 (`7 -> 6 -> 12 -> 24`), but your algorithm returns 4.

Comment: @Iłya Bursov,  5 -> 10 than cur * 2 >= 17, than return  cur - (target + 1) // 2 + 1 + (target % 2) which is 10 - (17 + 1) // 2 + 1 + 1 equals 3, plus 5 -> 10, answer is 4 , which is correct

Comment: @Iłya Bursov but if initial value is N=5, T=17, than it wil do 5 -> 10 right? than one possible way is 10 -> 9 -> 18 ->17,  do I miss something?

Comment: @EvilTak that's right, because above solution will always prefer move to cur * 2 if cur * 2 < target,,, so how can I fix it

Comment: They're asking for a shortest path. This looks like something that can be solved with Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: An obvious upper bound on the result is `abs(t-n)`, where `abs` means absolute value, since you can always go from `n` to `t` by a simple sequence of +1 (or -1). You can use that to make sure Dijkstra's algorithm terminates. Keep a dictionary that maps integers to their distance from `n`. When querying the dictionary, use the default value `abs(t-n)`. Dijkstra's algorithm will explore all integers at distance at most `abs(t-n)` from `n`. This is a bit overkill - there should be a more clever way to stop the algorithm.

Comment: @Stef hey, I use BFS instead of Dijkstra to find shortest distance, please check the update  answer to see if the code is correct, thanks!

Comment: What is the maximum limit of `T` or `N`. Like if `1 <= T <= 1e6` then you can do this just using linear DP. I think though BFS is good as well but Dp seems much more convincing in this case to me.

Comment: @risingStark does the linear DP you suggest the same idea as the first code above ? That DP method cannot pass some corner case mentioned in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to start from the target `T` and to found how many iterations we need to go down to initial value `N`. Here, the allowed operations are +1, -1 and division by 2.

The key point is that division by 2 is only allowed for even value of `T`. Moreover, if `T` is even effectively, then it seems clear that division by 2 is the road to take, except if `T` is near enough to `N`. This little issue is solved by comparing `1 + nsteps(N, T/2)` with  `T - N`.

If `T` is odd, we must have to compare `nsteps(N, T-1)` with `nsteps(N, T+1)`.

Last but not least, if `T` is less than `N`, then the number of steps is equal to `N - T`.

Complexity:  ??

Here is a simple C++ implementation to illustrate the algorithm. It should be easy to adapt it in any language.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int nsteps (int n, int t) {
    if (t <= n) {
        return n - t;
    }
    if (t%2 == 0) {
        return std::min (1 + nsteps(n, t/2), t-n);
    }
    return 1 + std::min (nsteps(n, t-1), nsteps(n, t+1));
}
    
int main () {
    int n, t;
    std::cin >> n >> t;
    std::cout << nsteps (n, t) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In practice, as noted in a comment by @David Eisenstat, it is still slow, at least in some occasions. For example, for an input `1 1431655765`, it needs 10891541 calls of the function. I modified the code hereafter, by using the value of `T` modulo 4 in order to speed it up: if `T` is large enough, we can decide betweens the two roads when `T`is odd. In the same test case, only 46 calls are needed now.

In this case, the complexity seems indeed equal to O(log T).

```cpp
int cpt2 = 0;
long long int nsteps2 (long long int n, long long int t) {
    cpt2++;
    if (t <= n) {
        return n - t;
    }
    if (t%2 == 0) {
        return std::min (1ll + nsteps2(n, t/2), t-n);
    }
    if (t/4 < n) return 1ll + std::min (nsteps2(n, t-1), nsteps2(n, t+1));
    if (t%4 == 1) return 1ll + nsteps2(n, t-1);
    else return 1ll + nsteps2(n, t+1);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I wonder can this method use a memoization to speed up, because there are lots of repeated calculation, by the way, what the time complexity  do you think the BFS method is?

Comment: @zenxy It's very likely Theta(target).

Comment: @zenxy Due to the low number of calls in the new version, I don't think memoization can really help. No many repeated calculations anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, we can make use of normal BFS search for this question as the direction for our movement between floor is given already as floor + 1 or floor - 1 or floor / 2. As per my understanding a floor / 2 movement is only possible if we are at an even floor.

Here is my java code for the same :

```java
int findSteps(int n, int t) {
    if (n > t) {
        return n - t;
    }
    if (n == t) {
        return 0;
    }
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    Set<Integer> visited = new HashSet<>();
    queue.offer(n);
    visited.add(n);
    int steps = 0;
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        int size = queue.size();
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            int currentFloor = queue.poll();
            if (currentFloor == t)
                return steps;
            int possibleMove1 = currentFloor + 1;
            int possibleMove2 = currentFloor - 1;
            int possibleMove3 = currentFloor % 2 == 0 ? currentFloor / 2 : -1;
           // out of bound conditions or visited condition 
            if (possibleMove1 < t && possibleMove1 > n && !visited(possibleMove1)) {
                queue.offer(possibleMove1);
                visited.add(possibleMove1);
            }
            if (possibleMove2 < t && possibleMove2 > n && !visited(possibleMove2)) {
                queue.offer(possibleMove2);
                visited.add(possibleMove2);
            }
            if (possibleMove3 < t && possibleMove3 > n && !visited(possibleMove3)) {
                queue.offer(possibleMove1);
                visited.add(possibleMove1);
            }
        }
        steps += 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note : There is some repeating codes that can be moved to a separate function and use that function instead.